# The integral of a character is $0$

Tags: topological-groups, characters, haar-measure

Let $G$ be an additive **compact** topological abelian group group and fix a Haar measure $\mu$ on it. Moreover let $\psi\in \hat G$ a **nontrivial** character, this means that $\psi:G\to S^1\subset \mathbb C^\ast$ is a continuous homomorphism.

Why do we have that
$$\int_G \psi d\mu=0\;?$$

Can you give at least a hint for the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the translation invariance after a change of variables. Let $h\in G$ so that $\psi(h^{-1})\ne 1$ (which exists by non-triviality)

> $$\int_G\psi(g) d\mu(g) = \int_G\psi(h^{-1}g) d\mu(h^{-1}g)$$
>   $$=\psi(h^{-1})\int_G\psi(g)d\mu(g)$$

so the integral must be zero.

Comment: We use the compactness of $G$ just to ensure that the integral is finite. Is it right?

Comment: @notsure yes you want to be certain that you have integrability or else the integration won't make sense.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: the operation in $G$ is the addition not the multiplication, so you should change your answer. By the way thank you very much, the answer is clear.

Comment: @notsure you didn't specify what symbol you were using for your group operation, so I used my preferred notation which is multiplicative. It's purely notational though, $gh$ stands for the result of applying group operation to $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Yes, of course :) don't worry