# Simple Change of Variables in Lebesgue Integration

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, change-of-variable

I'm not sure if these details matter, but anyway for this particular case, consider a compact abelian group $G$ with operation $\cdot$, a Haar measure $\mu$ on it and $f$ a non-trivial character on $G$. (I'm looking at this question: [The integral of a character is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168834/the-integral-of-a-character-is-0))

I've seen stated that for $x,y\in G$,

$$\int_G f(x)\>d\mu(x)=\int_G f(x\cdot y)\>d\mu(x\cdot y).$$

Is this true? If so why? What's the general theory behind it?

Comment: Hint: recall the definition of (right/left) Haar measure (in particular, recall that $\mu(xA)=\mu(A)$). First show that the equation holds for simple functions, and then use a density argument to prove the general case.

Comment: @ManuelNorman I think the part that's tripping me up is if we know $\mu(xA)=\mu(A)$, why does that hold for $d\mu$?

Comment: This is usually a choice of notation: for instance, you could also simply write $d \mu$, or $\mu (dx)$; sometimes, it is not even explicitely written.